# pytest: invoke doctest without running unit tests

Tags: python, pytest, doctest

I want to test an example that I just added to a docstring. I can test it by hand with the `doctest` module:

```
import doctest
import path.to.mymodule


doctest.testmod(mymodule)
```

but this doesn't easily iterate over all modules like pytest (and would not capture other differences in how pytest wraps it)

I can also run `pytest --doctest-modules myproject/tests/ # other flags, etc.` but the test suite takes roughly 20 minutes, so that's not going to work.

So I want to test the docstrings, but not wait for unit tests to run. I tried `pytest -v --doctest-modules --ignore=/path/to/tests/` but it hangs and I give up after waiting a minute (collecting tests usually takes a few seconds).

I want to do this in as similar a manner as happens when pytest calls it, since that's what matters for CI.

Comment: `pytest -v --doctest-modules path/to/module.py`? Or `pytest -v --doctest-modules path/to/module.py::path.to.module.Class.method` if you want to run a single docstring.

Comment: Ah, of course, this works perfectly. I've never pointed pytest directly to the module, so it never occurred to me that I could just point it to the method directly. Thanks!